# What is the meaning and grammatical function of "tout" in "se faire tout un film"?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, adverbes

I recently learned the expression "se faire des films" or "se faire tout un film".

I am wondering what the meaning and grammatical role is of the word "tout".

For example, if I consider

> Tu te fais un film

I can translate (literally) as "You make to yourself a film". That is, the "te" is an indirect object, and "un film" is a direct object.

But with

> Tu te fais tout un film

, I'm not sure what "tout" does.

- Is it an adverb, modifying "fais", meaning "in a way that does it 100% completely", to give the sentence "You make to yourself, in a 100% complete way, a film"?
- Or is it instead some kind of additional object, meaning something like "everything that exists", as in "You make (to yourself) everything that exists into a film"?
- Or is it an adjective modifying "un film", meaning "You make (to yourself) a complete film"?

Comment: "Film" is a masculine word. "Un film". If you are not sure about the gender of a word, don't guess, open a dictionary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the third option. (*You make (to yourself) a complete film*). It would be a better translation to use "*whole*" instead of *complete*.

It basically just amplifies what's behind it, like it's not just a "mini-movie" or a short, he's really imagining a whole movie (so he's imagining something way too big that will never happen).

Other example :

> -T'as un pansement ? Tu t'es fait quoi au doigt ? (*You have a band-aid? What happened to your finger?*)
>
> -Oh, c'est toute une histoire (*Oh it's a whole story*)

i.e. there's so much leading to that event that the events make a whole story.

Comment: 1) Why is it "fait" instead of "fais" in "Tu t'es fait quoi au doigt"? 2) If I had wanted to modify the verb ("fais") instead, in "Tu te fais un film", would it be "Tu te tout fais un film"?

Comment: @silph 1) It's past participle, like "J'ai mangé" or "Je me suis trompé" : "Je me suis fait" (the conjugated verb is the auxiliary, *être*).

Comment: @silph 2) No, why would it be that way? "Tout" stays close to the noun "*Tout un film*", "*toute une histoire*"

Answer (score 4):

In this sentence, "tout" is an indefinite adjective, modifying the indefinite article "un" of "un film". It is used to denote the idea of a "whole/entire" thing, here an "entire movie". Basically, if you say "se faire tout un film", you are not just imagining a movie, you are imagining a *whole* movie, from A to Z, which involves more effort, goes into more details...